# I am trying to redirect to the show action(so I can see the new post) if a save is successful in the create action, but getting error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I am trying to redirect to the show action after a successful create action in order to see the post the user just made (Post controller).  I am getting this error message:

syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

More debugging info:
    unless source.valid_encoding?
    raise WrongEncodingError.new(@source, Encoding.default_internal)
    end

```
begin

mod.module_eval(source, identifier, 0)

ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, Finalizer[method_name, mod])

rescue => e # errors from template code

if logger = (view && view.logger)

logger.debug "ERROR: compiling #{method_name} RAISED #{e}"

logger.debug "Function body: #{source}"
```

Here is the Post Controller

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @posts = Post.all
    end


    def show
       @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
       @post = Post.new(params[:id])
    end

    def create
       @post = Post.new(params[:id])

       if @post.save
         redirect_to @post
       else
         render :new
       end
    end
end
```

Here is my show view:

```
<h1>Posts</h1> 


Title: <%= post.title %><br>
Body: <%= post.body %><br>
url: <%= post.url %><br>
<% end %>
```

index view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Thanks for your help.  I can't find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHOW** view must be:

`<h1>Post</h1> 
Title: <%= @post.title %><br>
 Body: <%= @post.body %><br>`

**INDEX** view must be:

`<h1>Posts</h1> 
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
Title: <%= post.title %><br>
 Body: <%= post.body %><br>
<% end %>`

---

Also change create action to such:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And add to controller (before last `end`):

```
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :url) #here you put all attributes you want be able to assign when creating the post
end
```

Comment: Did all this and I get an error that "post" is an undefined method or variable in the show view?

Comment: copy paste again and problem will be eliminated.

Comment: I did and now it says "title" is an undefined method?

Comment: It means all is working. check your db if it has title column. check syntax, if it is wtitten exsctly as in view (case also matters)

Comment: Yes thank you.  I just had to fix the names of my db columns up a little and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass `id` of new object which is required for action show

```
redirect_to post_path(@post)
```

or according to [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) (see chapter "4 Parameters") you can write

```
if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
else
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Okay now it redirects to the show view after the post is created, but I can't see the newly created posts.

Comment: I updated the question with current code and an updated error message.

Comment: does your `show` page work?! 1. What is `<% end %>` at the end of view. 2. you define variable `@post` in controller so you need `<%= @post.title %>` - without this it should raise undefined method 'post'

Comment: The show page still doesn't work after a post is created, I just get that error message I put in the question.  I got rid of the <% end %> and I do have <% @post.title %> in my show view.  Or do you mean put it somewhere else?

Comment: You should remove `<% end %>` because you have not started any block.