# I keep getting this error message even after I include attribute methods: match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.1

I am trying to get my Posts controller to work and I keep getting these error messages:

```
undefined method 'each' for `#<Post:0x000000062820c0>`   

and : match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
```

I just included Attribute Methods but the error is still the same.  I am posting my controller file below.  Thanks for the help.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods  #Just added this..the error message was the    

#same without it.


def new
 @post = Post.new
end

def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

if @post.save
  redirect_to @post #.find(params[:id])
else
  render :new
end
end

def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id]) # show
end

private

def post_params
params.require(:Title).permit(:Body, :url) 
end

end
```

Here is the show view:

```
<h1>Posts</h1> 

<% @post.each do |post| %> 
Title: <%= post.Title %><br>
Body: <%= post.Body %><br>
url: <%= post.url %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "Keep getting"? Getting when? Obviously `each` makes no sense on a single `Post`, so I suspect the error is actually in your view, maybe in the index? But you need to provide more information, there's little here we can use to help yet.

Comment: I am adding my show view to the question now.

Comment: There is no `each` on a single object, only on arrays/enumerables.

Comment: There's nothing to iterate over.

Comment: How do I fix this?  Doesn't it have the posts to iterate over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHOW** action:
Delete this line `@post.each do |post|` 
and also change these lines:

`Title: <%= post.Title %><br>
 Body: <%= post.Body %><br>`

to

`Title: <%= @post.title %><br>
 Body: <%= @post.body %><br>`

**INDEX** action:
Instead of `@post.each do |post|` 
do

`<% @posts.each do |post| %>
Title: <%= post.title %><br>
 Body: <%= post.body %><br>`

To be able to use it you would also want to add `index` action:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

---

Recommendation:
Your `post_params` method is not written right. Instead do:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :url) 
end
```

What this method does is whitelisting permitted to massassignment parameters. [Check this](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) for more info.

Comment: I did this and the original error message is gone and replaced by this "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"  The error is in the @post.each do |post| line

Comment: @posts.each do |post|  goes in the index view?? I am still getting the same error message with or without it there.

Comment: Okay now I get this error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass  And it is coming from <% @posts.each do |post| %> in the show view.

Comment: This is what my index view is right now : <% @posts.each do |post| %>  and yes I added the index action.  Could it have something to do with some instance variables being post and some being posts, I just played around with that and it didn't fix anything

Comment: I did it and now its back to the original error messages: match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super                            and: undefined method `each' for #<Post:0x00000006dbca80>

Comment: i beg you to check every letter. It matters. Read CAREFULLY what is in my answer, please

Comment: should my instance variables be @post or @posts?  In the index action it is posts and all my other actions are just post.

Comment: I forgot to delete the first line out of my show view.  Now I'm getting this error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input         and the problem seems to have something to do with this :
actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb

Comment: so check the syntax carefully (, < %> {} signs whatsoever). and please accept the answer as the issue from the question is solved.

Comment: Thank you.  I have another question if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376395/i-am-trying-to-redirect-to-the-show-actionso-i-can-see-the-new-post-if-a-save